# Grep vs Filter in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, filter

I was wondering about the differences between Grep and Filter :

Filter :

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
>   pass the function's test.

Grep :

> Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter
>   function. The original array is not affected.

**ok.**

so if I do this in GREP :

```
var arr = [ 1, 9, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1 ];

myNewArray= jQuery.grep(arr, function(n, i){
  return (n != 5 && i > 4);
});
```

I could do also :

```
 var arr = [ 1, 9, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1 ];

myNewArray= $(arr).filter( function(n, i){
  return (n != 5 && i > 4);
});
```

In both situations I still can access to the original array...

so...where is the difference ?

Comment: I think `.grep()` is a helper method for general array processing, while `.filter()` is typically used for narrowing down element selections. I don't think `.grep()` returns a jQuery object, and you can't chain it (`jQuery.fn.grep` does not exist).

Comment: `$(arr).filter` <- this is unnecesary, do `arr.filter` instead.

Comment: Mahn not supported widely

Answer (score 139, accepted):

They both function in similar ways however they differ in their usages.

The filter function is intended to be used with html elements, and that is why it is a chainable function that returns a jQuery object and it accepts filters like ":even", ":odd" or ":visible" etc. You can't do that with the grep function, which is intended to be a utility function for arrays.

Comment: Just wanted to highlight that .filter() doesn't work in IE, so better to use $.grep() in case your app supports all browsers.

Comment: tested and found that currently .filter() works in IE as well as Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 20):

Filter is part of jQuery.fn so it's aim is to be used with selector `$('div').filter` where grep is a jQuery tool method (`jQuery.grep`)

Comment: True, the normal usage of filter is to pass a selector string. You can also pass a filter function, although the arguments (index, item) are opposite of the native filter function (item, index). Also, grep seems to be very similar to the native array filter function. I suspect that the advantage of grep for jquery is compatibility with older browsers...

Answer (score 6):

The difference in its usage:

Filter:

> ```
> $(selector).filter(selector/function)
> ```

Grep:

> ```
> $.grep(array,function,invert)
> ```

So in your case I would rather use `grep()` because using array this way is unnecessary: `$(arr)`.

I also suppose that `grep` function is faster, because it only accepts arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To those that are interested on how `grep` performs against `filter` I wrote this test:

**TLDR;** Grep is many times faster.

Script I used for testing:

```js
function test(){
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i<1000000; i++)
{
array.push(i);
}

var filterResult = []
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
var stime = new Date();
var filter = array.filter(o => o == 99999);
filterResult.push(new Date() - stime);
}

var grepResult = [];
var stime = new Date();
var grep = $.grep(array,function(i,o){
return o == 99999;
});
grepResult.push(new Date() - stime);

$('p').text('average filter - '+(filterResult.reduce((pv,cv)=>{ return pv +cv},0)/1000))
$('div').text('average grep - '+(grepResult.reduce((pv,cv)=>{ return pv + cv},0)/1000))
}
test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Matas Vaitkevicius, the code snippet posted presents errors, here is a corrected one:

```js
function test(){
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i<1000000; i++)
{
    array.push(i);
}

var filterResult = []
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    var stime = new Date();
    var filter = array.filter(o => o == 99999);
    filterResult.push(new Date() - stime);
}

var grepResult = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    var stime = new Date();
    var grep = $.grep(array,function(i,o){
        return o == 99999;
    });
    grepResult.push(new Date() - stime);
}

$('p').text('average filter - '+(filterResult.reduce((pv,cv)=>{ return pv +cv},0)/1000))
$('div').text('average grep - '+(grepResult.reduce((pv,cv)=>{ return pv + cv},0)/1000))
}
test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<div></div>
```

**TLDR :** In firefox, filter is slightly faster, in chrome, that's the opposite. Regarding performances only, you can use anyone.