# Using indexOf( ) to check if particular object exists in JS Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is the structure of my Array:

```
[{"stockCode":"PALLET CARDS","quantity":"2"},
 {"stockCode":"PALLET CARDS","quantity":"3"},
 {"stockCode":"CBL202659/A","quantity":"1"},
 {"stockCode":"CBL201764","quantity":"3"}]
```

When the order `button` is clicked I would like to check if a `stockCode` exists in this `array`. However each time I do this I get -1 returned.

This is the code where I check for the `stockCode`:

```
$(".orderBtn").click(function(event){
        //Check to ensure quantity > 0
        if(quantity == 0){
            console.log("Quantity must be greater than 0")
        }else{//It is so continue
            //Show the order Box
            $(".order-alert").show();
            event.preventDefault();

            //Get reference to the product clicked
            var stockCode = $(this).closest('li').find('.stock_code').html();
            //Get reference to the quantity selected
            var quantity = $(this).closest('li').find('.order_amount').val();

            //Order Item (contains stockCode and Quantity) - Can add whatever data I like here
            var orderItem = {
            'stockCode' : stockCode,
            'quantity'  : quantity
            };

            //Check if cookie exists 
            if($.cookie('order_cookie') === undefined){

            console.log("Creating new cookie");
            //Add object to the Array
            productArray.push(orderItem);

            }else{//Already exists

            console.log("Updating the cookie")
            productArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('order_cookie'));

            //Check if the item already exists in the Cookie and update qty
            if(productArray.indexOf(stockCode)!= -1){

                //Get the original item and update
                console.log("UPDATING EXISTING ENTRY " + productArray.indexOf("PALLET CARDS"));
            }
            else{
                console.log("ADDING NEW ENTRY ");
                //Insert the item into the Array
                //productArray.push(orderItem);
            }
            }
        }

        //Update the Cookie
        $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });

        //Testing output of Cookie
        console.log($.cookie('order_cookie'));
    });
```

I get a reference to the stockCode when the user clicks on the order `button`:

```
        var stockCode = $(this).closest('li').find('.stock_code').html();
```

I would like to check if this stockCode is already in the `array` and if it is then I will not be adding a new entry, but rather, updating an existing one.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array) this has been asked before... You can't do a straight indexOf on an object array. You have to compare each element in the array.

Comment: question still unanswered?

Answer (score 3):

i hope I'm getting you right:

```
   function findByStockCode(code, stockCodeArr){
           return stockCodeArr.filter(function(elem){
              return elem.stockCode == code;
           });
   }
```

this ofcourse would give you an array back. If the length is greater than zero an element with the given code is in the array already. I think the filter-function has been added at ECMA5 so probably IE8 won't support it. 
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter][1] mentions a fallback for the case that filter is not implemented in the current browser. 
Anyway there's a similiar jQuery-function that in which 'this' refers to the actual element:

```
function jQueryFindByStockCode(code, stockCodeArr){
               return $(stockCodeArr).filter(function(){
                  return this.stockCode == code;
               });
       }
```

**Edit:** 
As DhruvPathak mentioned $.grep might be a more appropriate solution than jQuery's filter. ([Grep vs Filter in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139916/grep-vs-filter-in-jquery)) 
I looked up again for a solution with a better performance (seems) you have it to write on your own (it's pretty simple anyway):

```
//for defined, non-null values
function findFirstByProperty(arr, prop, value){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
         if(arr[i]!=null && "undefined" !== typeof arr[i] && arr[i][prop] == value) 
             return arr[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

This should have a better performance (especially for big arrays). In average (assuming there's such an element in array) it should in average be **twice as fast** as filter and grep (since it stops at first match).

Comment: You should actually use jQuery's `$.grep` method (as mentioned by @DhruvPathak) for this instead of `$().filter`, as the second is for DOM collections.

Comment: I had a mistaken memory of grep. I thought it would stop at first found element. So both solutions seem to have a non-perfect performance for this issue. Maybe a own function should be written here for performance-hunters.

Comment: That would be [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in Harmony.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `grep` , to match elements of your array which have "stockcode" key equal to your stockCode

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to use like this :

```
$.inArray( stockCode, productArray)
```

More information [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/).

Comment: before downvoting can someone dare to put comment

Comment: then what is the issue?